# ¿Cómo puedo borrar la bandeja de entrada de sms de android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, android-permissions, sms

Desarrollé una app que me permite la gestión de los sms del teléfono. Los permisos declarados en el **manifest** son los siguientes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Ahora bien, mi problema es el siguiente: Pretendo, atraves de una rutina recorrer la bandeja de entrada de SMS a traves de un cursor, guardarla en una base de datos externa y luego eliminarla del teléfono.

```
public void EnviarBandeja(){

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexId = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int indexBody = cur.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddr = cur.getColumnIndex("address");
    int indexDate = cur.getColumnIndex("date");
    int indexDateS = cur.getColumnIndex("date_sent");
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) { /* false = no sms */
        do {

            Date date = new Date(cur.getLong(indexDate));
            String DateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(date);

            Date dateS = new Date(cur.getLong(indexDateS));
            String DateFS = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(dateS);

            GuardarSms(cur.getString( indexId ),cur.getString( indexBody ),cur.getString( indexAddr ),DateFS);

        //borrar sms
        //String uri = "content://sms/"+cur.getInt( indexId );
        //getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
        //


            //String str = "Sender: " + cur.getString( indexId ) + "\n" + cur.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cur.getString( indexBody )+ "\n" + DateF + "\n" + DateFS;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Procesando envio ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } while (cur.moveToNext());



    }

}
```

Hasta este punto he llegado a guardar la bandeja más no eliminarla, por ello las lineas para ello se encuentran comentadas. La rutina GuardarSms, que usa como conexión http la libreria Volley es la siguiente.

```
  public void GuardarSms( String tid, String body, String addr, String Date){

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo

    map.put("ban_phone_id", tid);
    map.put("ban_gsm", addr);
    map.put("ban_body", body);
    map.put("ban_fec_re", Date);


    // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

    // Depurando objeto Json...
    Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext ()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    Constantes.INSERT_BAN,
                    jobject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // Procesar la respuesta del servidor
                            //procesarRespuesta(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Mi problema verdaderamente es conseguir luego de guardar cada sms, borrarlo; con las lineas para borrar corriendo los resultados que tengo son los siguientes:

-En android <5.0 esta rutina solo registra el primer sms y luego empieza a borrar toda la bandeja de entrada.

-En android >6.0 la rutina solo registra los sms. No se elimina ningún sms.

Sobre esto, según fuentes a partir de Lollipop hace falta adicional al permiso WRITE_SMS que la aplicación este declarada como predeterminada para mensajería. Cosa que tampoco he conseguido.

Agradeceré mucho a quien se tomase el tiempo de ayudarme a aclarar el tema.

Comment: En android 6.0 estas requiriendo los permisos manualmente, y aceptandolos?

Comment: Hola Jorge, he verificado que la app tenga habilitados los permisos y así es. Lo que estoy intentando ahora es hacer que android tome a la app como defecto para mensajería.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba que la aplicación pregunte de forma explicita el permiso de escribir SMS y leer SMS en la actividad donde realizas el proceso de borrado, ya que en android 5 para arriba los permisos relacionados a los SMS te los engloba, pero por seguridad, intenta pedir los permisos al sistema y no solo solicites uno, igual, aunque no lo muestras en el código verifica que estes solicitando el permiso por medio de este código:
A mi no me dejaba recibir SMS si no ponia explicitamente la pregunta, aunque en mi manifest y en el gestor de permisos de android estuviera activo el permiso, asi que tuve que preguntar por el permiso a fuerzas.

***Leer SMS***

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},255);
}
```

***Recibir SMS***

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)) {
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},255);
}
```

Espero te ayude la respuesta.

Comment: Se me olvidó comentar que este código lo probe en Android 9 y funciona